# miDate y maxDate Dateranguepicker

Tags: javascript, daterangepicker

estoy haciendo un sistema de reservas. Algunas de ellas solo pueden estar disponibles un rango de fechas y otras que son la mayoría están disponibles todo el año. Viendo la documentación veo que existe el campo `minDate` y `maxDate`. Aquí está la [documentación](https://www.daterangepicker.com/).

Pero realizando una simple prueba a mi no me funciona, me deja libre todos los días.

```
$('.select_fechas').daterangepicker({
   isInvalidDate: function(date) {
   //console.log(momentDates)
     return momentDates.reduce(function(bool, range) {
      return bool || (date >= range.start && date <= range.end);
     }, false);
   },
   isCustomDate: function(date) {
     var daySettings = 'day_green';
       momentDates.reduce(function(bool, range) {
         if(date >= range.start && date <= range.end){
            daySettings = 'day_red';
          }
       }, false);
          return daySettings;
     },

     autoApply: true,
     autoUpdateInput: false,
     "opens": "center",
     format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
     "minSpan": {
       "days": minDays
     },
     "maxSpan": {
       "days": maxDays
     },
     startDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
       endDate: new Date(new Date().getTime() + 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
       minDate: 29/08/2022,
       maxDate: 15/09/2022
     });

     $('.select_fechas').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
            $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
            $("#date_start").val(picker.startDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
            $("#date_start2").val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            $("#date_end").val(picker.endDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
            $("#date_end2").val(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
            //console.log(prueba);
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si alguien le sirve la respuesta.

Parece ser que la fecha tiene que estar de este modo para funcionar:

> 2022, 01, 25

Entonces lo que he hecho es cuando lo guardo en BD lo guardo en formato fecha, por ejemplo `2022-09-01`.

Cuando en la ficha de la propiedad quiero imprimir el valor para que lo reconozca dateranguepicker hago lo siguiente:

```
new Date(minDateMio.replace("-", ","));
```

Remplazo los guiones por "," y así funciona bien.